# What type of charts is using in ECMA-404?

Tags: json, parsing, ecma, translators

I found this figure in JSON spec

[image: chart]

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

1. Whats name of type of this chart?
2. Can I use this chart for specifying any programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are usually called [railroad diagrams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram), and they are basically a way of presenting a finite state automaton's transition diagram in a readable fashion. It is straight-forward to convert any regular expression into this format, but some regular expressions are tidier than others.

There are variations which work for context-free languages, so you will also find railroad diagrams for push-down automata. It is common that some high level of the grammar (for example, the non-terminal `statement`) can be expressed as a regular expression of lower-level components (such as `expression`).